# How to pass password to another program using python

Tags: python

I am using Python to call another application. I have tried with subprocess.call() and subprocess.popen() mathod with stdin and stdout parameter to run another application. I am able to open new new program but application require password to login. please help me, How to pass password to window application.

Comment: What application? How does it ask for password? We can't help you without knowing anything about the application.

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/how-to-use-the-pexpect-module-in-python
Check if this helps

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
import subprocess

args = [app_path, add_arguments]
process = subprocess.Popen(args, subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write(bytes(yourpwd + "\n"))
output = process.communicate()
```

While opening your application with Popen, you connect the standard input stream of this application with a Pipe that is managed by subprocess. Afterwards you can write directly to this stream, just like your a typing in a console window. However, you have to send everything with `process.communicate()`, since it finalizes your input and waits for the results of the program. Be aware, your application closes after calling `communicate`.

I have not found a workaround to avoid `process.communicate`. So if you like to have some kind of interactivity, you have to try something else.